# Ubuntu doesn't reconnect to WiFi unless I reboot

Tags: 12.04, drivers, wireless, broadcom, iwlwifi

I am dual-booting my laptop going between Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Initially, I can connect to WiFi, but if I get disconnected for some reason, or if I restart my router, Ubuntu won't reconnect unless I reboot my laptop. Just logging out and back in won't work, I have to restart ubuntu, why and how can I fix this?

The output of `sudo lshw -c network` is

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: e4:d5:3d:77:df:9d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) ip=192.168.1.105 latency=0
multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:16 memory:c2500000-c2503fff   *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: ec:9a:74:48:ce:63
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw
latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:44 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
```

I have installed Broadcom STA wireless driver. I have experienced the same issue before with other distros; Crunchbang doesn't connect to wireless at all, Archbang won't connect to wireless after upgrading pacman. The problem began with Ubuntu, which is why I tried both Crunchbang and Arch and then ended back at Ubuntu.

**The output of:**

[lsmod](http://dpaste.com/917795/)

[cat /etc/modules](http://dpaste.com/917796/)

[cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf](http://dpaste.com/917798/)

Comment: I have the opposite problem.  This never happened under 14.04 LTS for me. The upgrade to 16.04 LTS is so great I'll keep it, but it keeps forgetting my WiFi password.  The service is clearly running; just that it forgets the password and doesn't connect.  I posted this:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/934958/how-to-make-ubuntu-16-04-lts-remember-my-wifi-password-through-a-shutdown - and I do not want to deal with blacklisting or anything strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please provide the output of the following commands

```
lsmod
cat /etc/modules
cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

If you have b43 module running try blacklisting it and use the module wl or brcmsmac

```
vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add the following line to this file

```
blacklist b43
```

save the file

```
vim /etc/modules
```

add the following line to this file to load wl at boot time

```
wl
```

restart your pc

if it doesn't work

try reinstalling drivers using jockey

Comment: please read my edit

Comment: did you try blacklisting the b43 module and adding wl module to the list of modules to be loaded at boot time

Comment: http://dpaste.com/917798/ see line 35, it says `blacklist bcm43xx` so it's already blacklisted right? aren't you talking about that module?

Comment: no bcm43xx module was used in older versions of linux, blacklist b43 and add wl module to list of modules to be loaded at boot time and try again

Comment: `wl` didn't work but it seems that `brcmsmac` is working! Will that solve the issue with crunchbang or arch?

Comment: [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#brcmsmac.2Fbrcmfmac) might help for Arch

Answer (score 0):

Windows is turning off your wireless adapter thus working only when you turn on your computer.  You need to turn off the power management feature.  You do this through the control panel.

Start your control panel
Click on Network and Internet
Click on View network status
In the upper left side click on Change adapter settings
Right click on your wifi icon
In the drop down box click on Properties
Under the Connect Using heading click on configure
In the new box click the tab on the right Power Management
Unclick the Allow computer to turn off the device to save power button

Click save and close all windows
Restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

Temporary Fix - so that you don't have to restart your system. Try:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It restarts your `network-manager` which could solve your problem.