# How to make Ubuntu 16.04 LTS remember the WiFi password through a shutdown then later restart?

Tags: networking, wireless, password, shutdown, startup

**This problem is that Ubuntu 16.04 LTS does not remember the WiFi password through a shutdown then a later restart.**

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS had no problem with this.  I let it upgrade me to 16.04 LTS (after making a backup, of course).

First impression is that I like it.  It does take more RAM, but I can live with that.

Problem:  WiFi is my only connection, and every time it is started up it is not connected to the net at all.

**Clearly the service is running:  It pops up a green box saying that WiFi networks are available.**

When I click on the (up/down) icon in the upper right I see the list of routers.

Clicking on my router's name makes it pop up an empty box asking for the password.  It just plan doesn't remember the setting.

I never had this problem with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  It simply remembered and reconnected.

> Due to the location of this computer, the environment gets way too hot
>   during the day to leave it on all the time.  It can only be used
>   during the evening hours.

My question is in the title:  **How to make Ubuntu 16.04 LTS remember the WiFi password through a shutdown then later restart?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the connection is remembered with a password through the `Edit Connections` from the network tray symbol dropdown.

[image: Network Connections]

Jump into `edit` the connection and on the `General` tab automatic connection should be checked. If that's fine, check that there actually is a password remembered in the `Wifi-Security` tab.

[image: Security]

I feel like there may be more significant issues to your problem though, such as the router failing to authenticate your connection, but this is the first thing to check.

Comment: I didn't have to enter the creds but now that I go back I see they are in there, I guess because I was already logged in when I did this.  And in my case I simply deleted everything and started over.  You hit the nail on the head.  I just posted my answer of how I made it work.

Comment: This is working out great.  Now that this has been set I can RDP into the box right after it boots without requiring any kind of login.  TNX.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works:

Startup, get logged into the router.

Go to the (up/down) Icon.

Select Edit Connections.

**Delete them all.**  Ethernet and all the Wireless connections.

**Then create a new Wireless connection.**

It will have the box checked that says to automatically connect if available.

In the IPV4 section, set it to Manual.  Enter the address, tab then enter the gateway address of the router, then tab and enter the DNS server.

**-->  Check the box "Require IPv4 addressing for this connection to complete.**

> Also, I am always sure to mark the IPv6 portion to "Ignore" instead of
>   Automatic.  No need for it to waste time on something I don't use.

Then close it all.

Shut down then start up.

It comes up connected to the WiFi immediately!

**So the problem is now solved.**